# Getting trouble to get the file count or file list of a large mounted drive

Tags: linux, macos

I have a shared drive where I have more than 2 million of wmv files of around 2TB  total size. I am trying to access the drive by mounting it using smb protocol from my local MAC machine. When I run "

> $ ls -a | wc -l

command to check the total count of files. I am getting different result every time. e.g if sometime I get the result as X then next time I am getting another result Y Here is the sample output [sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R4yk.png), which should not be as no other person is accessing this drive. When I investigate more I come to know that "ls" command output is different every time. This command should work as I have been using them since decade. Is it something I am doing wrong or in a large volume of data or network shared drive, this command fails ? I am sure there is no access or network issue while I am doing this activity. Any hint or work around will be much appreciated

Comment: Hi, your question is not entirely clear. What is the output that you are getting and what were you expecting?

Comment: When I use that command some time I m getting 21090121 and for the same file with the same command I m getting 1589232

Comment: Thanks for the reply and Sorry.I am new to stack over flow .. I have attached the sample output and command

Comment: [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the similar issue when I tried to access shared location which is having around 200K numbers of file.In my case the shared drive file system was NTFS file system. I believe there is a compatibility issue with SMB protocol and NTFS file system. Finally I tried to mount the shared drive using "NFS" instead of "SMB" and I could able to get the correct number of files in my mounted drive. This problem never happened in WINDOWS as I have mounted much higher number of files earlier using Windows many time. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes . The shared drive was a NTFS. I mounted the drive using an another Windows machine and now getting the correct count every time. Thanks for the hint. You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because the file list is not immediately available to OSX from the network share. Apples implementation of SMB is still a bit buggy, unfortunately.

You may try: `defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool TRUE`

And see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I m using Finder--> Go -> Go To Folder to connect to the shared drive. Is this a terminal command  ??

Comment: Yes, it is for the terminal. If you want to reverse the command, just do it again with FALSE as the last parameter.

Comment: I have tried it but that did that not solve my issue.